# Problem in feature filling when exporting maps to image in Qgis Print Composer

Tags: maps, qgis

I am currently trying to export a map in Qgis to an image format (JPEG or PNG) using the Print Composer. I have three layers on the map and two of them are filled with a texture (lines for South America and dots for Africa and Asia). When looking inside the Qgis fillings seem just fine. However, when I export the map to image format and open it both lines and dots somewhat mingle and the fillings become blurred. Only when I zoom in enough the lines and dots become distinct again. I did some internet research, but I could not find anything useful. Is there a way to export the map to image format and yet keep the fillings similar to what is displayed inside the Qgis?

Thank you.